# ant script not expanding property value in exec arguments

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol, snapshotcm

i have an ant script as shown below:

```
<project name="nightly_build" default="main" basedir="checkout">
    <target name="init">
        <exec executable="C:/Work/Searchversion.exe"/>
        <property file="initial.properties"/>
        <property file="C:/Work/lastestbuild.properties"/>
        <tstamp>
            <format property="suffix" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss"/>
        </tstamp>
    </target>
    <target name="main" depends="init">
        <exec executable="C:/Program Files/True Blue Software/SnapshotCM/wco.exe">
            <arg line='-h sinsscm01.sin.ds.net -S"/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Version_Number}" /'/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

i created the above script to replicate a command: `wco -h sinsscm01.sin.ds.net -S"/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.014" /`

and `6.70.102.014` is found inside `latestbuild.properties` file in the form of:

`Version_Number = 6.70.102.014`

and this `latestbuild.properties` file is obtained when i execute `C:/Work/Searchversion.exe`

but when i execute this ant script using cruisecontrol, in my log file,

`[Thread-24] INFO  ScriptRunner     -      [exec] Cannot open snapshot 'sinsscm01.sin.ds.jdsu.net:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Version_Number}': No such snapshot`

where `${Version_Number}` should have been `6.70.102.014`

How do i tackle this issue?

EDIT 1:

after trial and error and substituting with a built in property ${ant.version}, i realise that my property file could be loaded in correctly over here. can anyone point out my mistake? i dont see anything wrong though

EDIT 2:

Just additional infomation... This is actually a delegate ant script for cruisecontrol(used to perform nightly build). Here is my config.xml file for per minute build:

```
<cruisecontrol>
    <project name="dms" buildafterfailed="true">
        <listeners>
            <currentbuildstatuslistener file = "logs/dms/status.txt"/>
        </listeners>
        <bootstrappers>
        </bootstrappers>
        <modificationset quietperiod="60">
            <alwaysbuild/>
        </modificationset>
        <schedule interval="60">
            <ant buildfile="nightly_build.xml" target="main"/>
        </schedule>
        <log dir="logs/dms">
            <merge dir="checkout/dms/build/test-results" />
        </log>
        <publishers>
        </publishers>
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

should properties file be loaded in config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You could add assertions in your init target that the required properties file exists and that the property is defined. For example:

```
<property name="version.file" value="C:/Work/lastestbuild.properties"/>
<available file="${version.file}" property="version.file.available"/>
<fail unless="version.file.available" message="file [${version.file}] is not available"/>
<property file="${version.file}"/>
<fail unless="version" message="property [version] is not defined"/>
<echo message="version: ${version}"/>
```

I think that will help you spot that the file does not exist.

I took a look at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5972962/127035) about this script you're putting together. In the code which writes the version number to file, you use filename `latestbuild.properties`:

```
 TextWriter latest = new StreamWriter("C:\\Work\\latestbuild.properties");
```

In your Ant script, you are loading a different filename `lastestbuild.properties`.

Unless you've fixed it since then, that will be your problem. (If you modified your external script to take the filename as a parameter, and defined the filename once as an Ant property - as in my sample above -  it would help you avoid this kind of problem.)

Regarding your discovery that you need to wait for your external script before continuing in Ant, take a look at the [Sleep](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sleep.html) task.

Comment: and also, i tried to perform the additional task as stated by your script and error is returned: `2011-05-13 09:37:19,978 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - C:\builds\nightly_build.xml:7: Problem: failed to create task or type avaliable
2011-05-13 09:37:19,993 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - Cause: The name is undefined.` in which line 7 is `<available file="${version.file}" property="version.file.available"/>`

Comment: hi, the above error still holds even after i changed the file name, thanks for pointing out the error. the error is still at the line `<available file="${version.file}" property="version.file.available"/>`

Comment: i found the problem, by inserting a few `<echo>` lines before executing, i will be able to delay time so that `searchversion.exe` file will have the time to generate the latestbuild.properties file

Comment: Your problem with the "available" task is given in the error message. It appears you typed "avaliable" instead of "available".

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your arguments to `wco.exe` into separate child elements like this:

```
<exec executable="C:/Program Files/True Blue Software/SnapshotCM/wco.exe">
    <arg value="-h" />
    <arg value="sinsscm01.sin.ds.net" />
    <arg value="-S" />
    <arg value="/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Version_Number}" />
    <arg value="/" />
</exec>
```

I think ant isn't expanding `${Version_Number}` because it is inside ' "..." ' in the version you posted.

As mentioned in the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) for `<exec>` you should avoid use of the `<arg line=...>` form.